# Retrofit RxJava Simple test

Tags: retrofit, rx-java

I'm learning Retrofit and RxJava and I'v created test to connect github:

```
public class GitHubServiceTests {
RestAdapter restAdapter;
GitHubService service;

@Before
public void setUp(){
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES)
        .create();

restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
        .setEndpoint("https://api.github.com")
        .setConverter(new GsonConverter(gson))
        .build();
service = restAdapter.create(GitHubService.class);
}

    @Test
public void GitHubUsersListObservableTest(){

   service.getObservableUserList().flatMap(Observable::from)
            .subscribe(user -> System.out.println(user.login));

}
```

when I execute test, I see nothing in my console. But when I execute another test

```
    @Test
public void GitHubUsersListTest(){
    List<User> users = service.getUsersList();
    for (User user : users) {
        System.out.println(user.login);
    }
```

it works, and I see user's logins in my console

Here is my Interface for Retrofit:

```
public interface GitHubService {
    @GET("/users")
    List<User> getUsersList();

    @GET("/users")
    Observable<List<User>> getObservableUserList();
}
```

where I'm wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because of the asynchronous call your test completes before a result is downloaded. That's typical issue and you have to 'tell' test to wait for the result. In plain java it would be:

```
@Test
public void GitHubUsersListObservableTest(){
   CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(N);
   service.getObservableUserList()
          .flatMap(Observable::from)
          .subscribe(user -> {
              System.out.println(user.login);   
              latch.countDown();
          });
   latch.await();
}
```

Or you can use [BlockingObservable](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/observables/BlockingObservable.html) from RxJava:

```
// This does not block.
BlockingObservable<User> observable = service.getObservableUserList()
    .flatMap(Observable::from)
    .toBlocking();

// This blocks and is called for every emitted item.
observable.forEach(user -> System.out.println(user.login));
```

Comment: Why not use observable toBlocking().first();

Comment: There are several methods: `first`, `last`, `single`,`forEach`, `toIterable`, `firstOrDefault`, etc. depending on your needs. Check the link to the BlockingObservable docu.